# Programmatically read memory from win32 dump file

Tags: winapi, memory, dump, crash-dumps

I have a Win32 core dump (full dump, with memory) of a process crash which was caused by a heap corruption.
I have full symbols and sources, so opening the dump in the debugger is not a problem.

I'm having problems locating certain values in the memory, and searching through all the data structures in VS's watch windows is problematic (too many to go through).

Is there any way I can access the memory programmatically?

As a simple example, I'd like to find an address in the dumped memory which holds a specific other address. I can complicate it more later once I have this basic example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load the dump file into the windbg debugger. Windbg [has a miniature scripting language](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johan/archive/2008/01/23/using-windbg-advanced-commands.aspx) you can use to drive operations programmatically. Or you can write a windbg [debugger extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if the algorithm you want is particularly complicated.

Comment: Thanks for these. The first link demonstrates debugging a .NET application. Are both of these links relevant for native code as well? (I forgot to mention It's a core dump of native code)

Comment: The scripting language applies to native debugging as well; they just used a managed example.